# If there is a probability p of something happening every day, what is the probability of it happening for a week?

Tags: probability

Let's say there's an 80% chance of rain today, tomorrow, and every day this week.  How do I calculate the probability of the chance it at least rains once over the course of a week?

Comment: Binomial, $p=0.8, n=7, x=7$ for the question in the title. Otherwise, use the cmplement rule for "at least one". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: "for a week" (title) or "it at least rains once" (text)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming independence, this will be one minus the probability that it never rains i.e. $$1-(1-0.8)^7\approx 0.99.$$

Comment: Right, I'll add that in. Thanks!